# How can i format a float variable in scala?

Tags: scala

i need to format this variable :

```
val value = 3.2202
```

in a number like this: 3.2

How can i make this in scala?
I don't want a string or a println...I need another float variable with 1 decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val floatVal = BigDecimal(3.2202).setScale(1, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).toFloat
```

Answer (score 3):

Use scala `f` interpolator and then do `toFloat`

```
val value = 3.2202 
val str = f"$value%.1f"
val result = str.toFloat
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val value = 3.2202
value: Double = 3.2202

scala> val str = f"$value%.1f"
str: String = 3.2

scala> val result = str.toFloat
result: Float = 3.2
```

`1` after `.` says consider only 1 decimal part of `value` after dot

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val value = 3.2202
value: Double = 3.2202

scala>     f"$value%.1f"
res0: String = 3.2

scala>     f"$value%.2f"
res1: String = 3.22

scala>     f"$value%.3f"
res2: String = 3.220

scala>     f"$value%.4f"
res3: String = 3.2202
```

The below output is important. Note that it adds extra 0 at the end.

```
scala>     f"$value%.5f"
res4: String = 3.22020
```

Comment: OP wrote: "I don't want a string or a println...I need another float variable with 1 decimal"...

Comment: i don't want a string... i need another float variable

Comment: @Mozzer just do `toFloat` after getting the string

Comment: @Mozzer it works. do `toFloat`. do not have any special chars in the string.

Comment: @Mozzer posted the repl output for you . just check it works bro

Comment: val ex= percentuali.percentuale_BA
      val stree = f"$ex%.1f"
      val result = stree.toFloat

I have this error [NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,4"]

Comment: @Mozzer dude ... why do you have `,` comma in the input. input is wrong dude. it should be `0.4` not `0,4`

Comment: @Mozzer `,` is invalid .. it will cause number format exception.

Comment: Ehi @pamu...my number is a result of a mathematical calculation (it is float)

Comment: the problem is that i need to insert this value in a json. When i make it, maybe the json conversion change the value...i don't know how can i make

Answer (score 2):

> in a number like this: 3.2 ... I need another float variable with 1 decimal.

This is impossible: there is no such thing as a float number with 1 decimal digit except for `something.5`. There is a float which is *printed* as 3.2 (and Tzach Zonar's answer explains how to get it), but it's actually [`3.2000000476837158203125`](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=051046050). If you want to represent decimal numbers exactly, use `BigDecimal`; that's what it's for.

You can read e.g. http://floating-point-gui.de/ to understand what "floating point" means and why 3.2 can't be represented as a binary floating point number (`float`, `double` or any higher precision).

Answer (score 1):

Would this to the trick?

```
scala> val value = 3.2202
value: Double = 3.2202

scala> val newVal = (value * 10).toInt / 10F
newVal: Float = 3.2
```

Comment: What is this *10/10D ?  Can you explain?
Another question..i need a float, not a doblue

Comment: Oh ok...i didn't saw the float method :D

Comment: changed to Float - multiplying by 10 and converting to int removes all the information after the first decimal place; Then dividing by 10F gives the float you wanted.

Comment: I have this  :
`percentuale_BA = (quantita.quantita_BA.toFloat * cento.toFloat)/(popolazione.abitanti_BA.toFloat)
     percentuale_Casamassima = ((quantita.quantita_Casamassima.toFloat * cento.toFloat) / popolazione.abitanti_Casamassima.toFloat)
    
How can i convert now percentuale_BA, percentuale_Casamassima etc.?

Comment: I can barely understand what you wrote (too much code in comments doesn't really work that well), but I guess `val new_percentuale_BA = (percentuale_BA * 10).toInt / 10F` and same idea for `percentuale_Casamassima`...

Comment: it doesn't work... the original value of percentuale_BA is: 0.39559483528137207

After your method i have 0.30000001192092896

Comment: odd... works for me (with 0.39559483528137207 as well)

Comment: are you sure you're not manipulating the result somehow after applying my suggested solution? I just can't figure out how this fails...

Comment: It's a project, so it is so complicate to explain all.
I'm not manipulate the value after your solution. I don't know why i have this result.

Comment: Don't need the Float->Int->Float conversion if you use: `(v*10).floor/10`